# Length contraction as $v>c$

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, faster-than-light

What would theoretically happen to an observed object's length (let it be a 5 meter line) moving at some speed greater than that of light in a straight path?

Comment: Have a look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80511/. Feed in a velocity greater than $c$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

A basic logical requirement for the Lorentz transformation is that it needs to be a one-to-one function. Otherwise, for example, different observers could disagree about whether two particles had collided. The Lorentz transformation is one-to-one for $v<c$, but at $v=c$ it isn't anymore. To make sense out of Lorentz transformations with $v>c$, one would therefore have to come up with a real-valued Lorentz transformation for $v>c$ and "glue" it onto the $v<c$ version. Recami (1986) shows how this can be done in 1+1 dimensions, but Gorini (1971) proves that it's impossible in 3+1 dimensions. (Basically you can only do this in $n+n$ dimensions, because FTL observers would interpret themselves as being in the STL sector, which requires a symmetry between spacelike and timelike vectors.)

In practical terms, if you tried to accelerate a physical object such as a meter-stick to $v>c$, you wouldn't be able to do it, since no continuous process of acceleration can provide a boost from a frame $\text{K}$ to a frame $\text{K}'$ in motion relative to $\text{K}$ at $v>c$. (This is a kinematic fact, and it holds regardless of dynamical considerations such as relativistic inertia.)

*References*

V. Gorini, "Linear Kinematical Groups," [*Commun. Math. Phys.* **21** no. 2 (1971), pp. 150-163](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01646749). [Open access via project Euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103857292).

E. Recami, "Special Relativity Extended to (antimatter and) Superluminal motions: A Review" (also "Classical tachyons and possible applications"), [*Riv. Nuovo Cimento* **9** no. 6 (1986) pp. 1-178](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02724327). Available from [Recami's web page](http://dinamico2.unibg.it/recami/scientific.htm).

Answer (score -2):

**mathematically** when a particle moves faster than the speed of light then lorentz factor will be an imaginary number that can be written as a real number multiplied imaginary unit,
$$\gamma=-i\Omega$$ where the $\Omega$ denotes [Estakhr Omega Factor](http://bit.ly/19Nivx5)
(check the link above for more information)

and if faster than the speed of Light becomes **technically** possible then it will be possible to build FTL (Faster Than Light) Particle accelerator and hadron collider.
**FTL-LHC**