# Understanding a step in the derivation of the length contraction effect in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation, lorentz-symmetry

I've been trying to figure out how the equation for length contraction is derived in my textbook (Krane, *Modern Physics* 3e) since a few of the final steps are omitted. The equation in question is:

$$
L = L_0/\gamma = L_0 \sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}
$$

Where $u$ is the velocity of the object. I managed to derive myself the previous equations

$$
\Delta t = \Delta t_0\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}
$$

and

$$
\Delta t = \frac{2L_0}{c} \frac{1}{1-u^2/c^2}
$$

after which my book states:

> Setting the two equations above equation to each other and solving, we obtain:
>   $$
> \Delta t = \Delta t_0\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2} = \frac{2L_0}{c} \frac{1}{1-u^2/c^2} \rightarrow L = L_0 \sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}
> $$

without any appearance of $L$ in the above equations. I have a hunch that it might be implicitly defined as $u\Delta t$, but I'm not certain. What is the missing step here in getting that last equation from the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear which bit is foxing you, so let's go through the argument:

[image: Light clock]

This is viewed from the Earth frame i.e. the frame in which the light clock is moving. In this frame the length iof the clock is $L$. In the outward trip the light moves a distance $L+ut_1$ in a time $t_1$, and since light moves at the speed of light we get:

$$ L+ut_1 = ct_1 $$

Likewise for the return trip the light moves a distance $L-ut_2$ in a time $t_2$ so:

$$ L-ut_1 = ct_2 $$

The total time is therefore:

$$ t = t_1 + t_2 = \frac{2L}{c}\frac{1}{1 - u^2/c^2} \tag{1} $$

Now switch to the rest frame of the clock. In this frame the length of the clock is $L_0$. In this frame the light simply moves a distance $2L_0$ in a time $t_0$, and again light moves at the speed of light so:

$$ t_0 = \frac{2L}{c} $$

Now the book uses the previously derived result that:

$$ t = \frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}} = \frac{2L_0/c}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}} \tag{2} $$

This is just the usual equation for time dilation. The time $t$ is the same time in equations (1) and (2), so we just set them equal to get:

$$ \frac{2L}{c}\frac{1}{1 - u^2/c^2} = \frac{2L_0/c}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}} $$

And this rearranges to the final result:

$$ L = L_0\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2} $$

But I have to say that this is a dreadful derivation of the Lorentz contraction because it give you no insight into what actually happens in special relativity. The contraction is not really a contraction it is a rotation in spacetime. Have a look at ["Reality" of length contraction in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148216/reality-of-length-contraction-in-sr/270063#270063) to get an idea of what is actually going on.

You might also be interested to look at [How do I derive the Lorentz contraction from the invariant interval?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80511/how-do-i-derive-the-lorentz-contraction-from-the-invariant-interval/80533#80533) to see how the Lorentz contraction is related to the symmetry that underlies special relativity.