# Lorentz Contraction from Minkowski Space

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

I looked at other similar questions, and couldn't find a fit.

I was reading [this resource](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Modern_Physics/Book%3A_Spiral_Modern_Physics_(D%27Alessandris)/3%3A_Spacetime_and_General_Relativity/3.1%3A_Minkowski_Metric), which claimed you could use Minkowski space :

$\delta{s}^2 = c^2 \delta{t}^2 - \delta{x}^2$

To calculate the Lorentz contraction :

$\gamma = {{1} \over {\sqrt{1 - {{v^2}\over{c^2}}}}}$

Unfortunately, the resource doesn't give a complete example of how this is done.

I tried a few other resources, and the best I could get was this:

$\delta{s}^2 = c^2 \rightarrow c^2 = c^2v_t^2 - v_x^2$

$\rightarrow 1 = v_t^2 - {{v_x^2} \over {c^2}}$

$\rightarrow v_t^2 = 1 + {{v_x^2} \over {c^2}}$

$\rightarrow v_t = \sqrt{1 + {{v_x^2} \over {c^2}}}$

However, these two terms $\gamma$ and $v_t$ do not look the same to me. What am I missing? How is this done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I derive the Lorentz contraction from the invariant interval?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80511/)

Comment: You’re right. Contraction. I’ll fix it.

Comment: The answer proposed is not correct

Comment: If dTau = dt sqrt( 1 - v^2 / c^2 ), v is close to c, and dt is 1; the answer proposed returns a dTau of near zero. Infinity is the expected result.